# Windows 10 touchpad Release Drag after Finger Lift on Dell Latitude E6510

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, dell-latitude

Having the same problem as "Windows 10 touchpad Release Drag after Finger Lift" but on a dell E6510. I lift finger after scrolling, move the cursor w/in the window and it keeps scrolling. Followed the advice of the original posts answer in registry but found no reference to finger release. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: P.S. It releases after about a half a second. I would prefer it release @ finger lift as all my laptops in the past have done. Thanks

Comment: Certain touchpad drivers in control panel have coast speed options. What model & Rev is yours?

Answer (score 0):

The Dell touchpad has a setting called "Draglock". I turned that setting off (unchecked it)

Go  into Windows Control Panel > Dell Touch Pad > Sensitivity >

Then Click on "Tapping" and disable the checkmark on "DragLock"

Answer (score -1):

In order to prevent the behavior you describe, you need to uncheck "Inertial Scrolling", within the Dell Touchpad application.

[image]

Comment: Please be more descriptive in future answers.  Unclear answers will be downvoted in the future.